# Video Skype on Aspire One

Tags: linux, skype, webcam, acer-aspire-one

I have an Acer Aspire One netbook with the default Linpus Lite OS.
It only supports video chat using Pidgin with MSN accounts.
All of my contacts have Skype or Google accounts set up, but not MSN.
Is it possible to video chat with Skype or Google contacts?
I would be willing to install a different OS in order to achieve this.

Comment: So you want to keep MSN and chat with Skype and Google Chat people through MSN? If you swap OS would you be still using MSN or would you at that point change to Skype and Google?

Comment: Pidgin supports text chat with all sorts of different accounts. I would use any account type for myself, but I want my contacts to keep using their current Skype or Google accounts, and I want to video chat with them. The hardware is there.

Answer (score 3):

[Skype for Linux](http://share.skype.com/sites/linux/2007/11/skype_20_beta_for_linux_with_video.html) has built-in support for video chat to other Skype users. I do not think you can import your Google or MSN contacts, so you would just have to use the Contact search in Skype to add them.

Skype is also on Windows, along with Google Talk (which supports video chat), so they are always possibilities.